# ng-click doesn't work on links created through jquery append

Tags: angularjs

If is use ng-click attribute of angular js script on statis links, it works well code shown below

```
<div class="modal fade" id="cModal" ng-controller="modalController">
  <li id="modalp1" class="active"><a ng-click="parentOptions()" href="#">Add Parent</a></li>
</div>
```

If sample link created dynamically through jquery append() or prepend() method, then click event doesnt work. sample code shown below.

```
$('#cpartners').prepend("<li><a ng-click=\"parentOptions()\" href=\"#\">Add Parents (Mother & Father)</a></li>");
```

Controller sample code shown below

```
function modalController($scope) {
  $scope.sthumbEdit = function() {
    $(".dur").show();
  };
  $scope.hthumbEdit = function() {
    $(".dur").hide();
  };
  $scope.parentOptions = function() {
  prepareParentOptions();
  };

  $scope.siblingOptions = function() {
   prepareSiblingOptions();
  };

  $scope.childOptions = function() {
   prepareChildOptions();
  };
```

}

Is there any way to enforce ng-click attribute works well on dyanmically generated links.

Answer (score 8):

if you add html using jquery, you need to compile the content and inject it into the DOM. Something like

`var element = $compile('<p>{{total}}</p>')(scope);`

See "How Directives are compiled" section for an example http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler

Comment: if u r calling it from outside the normal scope of angular use :angular.element(app_element).injector().get('$compile')('<p>{{total}}</p>')($rootScope);

Answer (score 1):

Changing the DOM directly from the controller is a mistake, you should not do it instead you need to use directives to create your "custom elements" and services.

using directly Jquery to edit your DOM if you are using AngularJS is counterproductive, 
if you want to use Jquery you have to wrap it inside a directive.

i recommend you the [AngularJS tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) for a good understanding of AngularJS, and [NGmodules](http://ngmodules.org/modules) that contains a lot of Angularjs Modules that can help you.

Comment: thanks for useful info. actual application is built into jquery. i will review and step by step replace its architecture to angular js.